# Stress testing Apache Tomcat app

Tags: tomcat, jmeter, stress-testing

How can I stress test apache tomcat app? I tried using Jmeter but i get an error after a certain number of users.

`org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException: Truncated chunk ( expected size: 8094; actual size: 6479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1814)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:440)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:433)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1636)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:519)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:493)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is telling you that your tomcat (mostt probably the  underlying application) is returning corrupt response (did you face an OOM ?) which might indicate a performance issue on tomcat side (which is what you expect from load testing).

But ensure before starting to tune Tomcat that you follow:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Comment: Tomcat should not be failing to return valid responses. Instead, Tomcat should be refusing to accept new requests. If you think you can demonstrate a situation where Tomcat begins to corrupt responses, please head-over to the Tomcat development mailing list and post a message to that effect. We would consider it to be a serious bug if Tomcat were to be corrupting responses under load.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherSchultz, From provided elements by asker it is just an hypothesis (it could be the underlying app that had an OOM for example), I doubt it's a Tomcat issue, more an app issue.

Comment: The application shouldn't be able to forge chunk lengths in a chunked response. So even if the application is broken, Tomcat should return a sane response. There may be a timeout involved, though. I'm not super-familiar with Apache http-client.